# How to add "onchange" SimpleAttributeModifier to DropDownChoice in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, wicket, dropdownchoice

I want to run a particular javascript when selection is changed in the drop down choice, so I added a simple attribute modifier like this :

```
ddc.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onchange", "calc();"));
```

But if I do this, it completely overrides the wicket onSelectionChanged() method.
I need a way to perform both.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an AttributeAppender

```
ddc.add(new AttributeAppender("onchange", "calc();", " "));
```

The last argument is the separator used.

Comment: yeah but i find the answer by Robert Niestroj more elegant, please accept one of the answers as the solution, so others know what worked.

Comment: I like the first one because it's just one line :D

Answer (score 4):

Use an [`OnChangeAjaxBehavior`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/OnChangeAjaxBehavior.html) for this like this:

```
    ddc.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.appendJavaScript("calc();");
        }
    });
```